# Spellchecker is not working in tinymce 4.0 (Non JSON response)

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, spell-checking

I'm trying to use Spellchecker in TinyMCE 4.0, but it returns the error:

```
Non JSON response:<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() [<a href='function.call-user-func-array'>function.call-user-func-array</a>]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'PSpellShell::spellcheck' was given in <b>/home/www/misitio.com/doc/plugins/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/rpc.php</b> on line <b>98</b><br />
{"id":null,"result":null,"error":null}
```

The code I use is:

```
//Javascript:
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        language : 'es',
        menubar : false,
        height: 400,
        autoresize_min_height: 400,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap hr",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualchars fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime table contextmenu directionality",
            "template textcolor autoresize spellchecker"
        ],
        toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor | subscript superscript | removeformat blockquote | charmap inserttime | link image | table hr | searchreplace | fullscreen spellchecker",
        image_advtab: true,
        spellchecker_languages : "+English=en",
        spellchecker_rpc_url: 'plugins/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/rpc.php'
    });
```

with plugin PHP Spellchecker 2.0.6.1 (http://www.tinymce.com/develop/changelog/?type=phpspell)

I think that you can fix connection problems with Google trying to https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce_spellchecker_php just do not see how to integrate it, Has anyone been able to use the Spellchecker in TinyMCE 4.0? or do they know of any tutorial to integrate Spellchecker to TinyMCE 4.0?

Well, thank you! : D

Comment: Do you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same problem in Wordpress 3.3.1.

Comment: Finally, I use the browser checker with this code:
  
  gecko_spellcheck : true,
  browser_spellcheck : true,

Comment: OK, thanks. I ended up installing AfterTheDeadline, and disabling the TinyMCE built-in spell checker.

Comment: @sgb004 did you solve this problem?

Comment: Really, not, I use the browser checker with this code: gecko_spellcheck : true, browser_spellcheck : true, this not work with ie

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by updating few lines in php spell checker plugin.

1) Rename "&checkWords" method to "&spellcheck" of EnchantSpell, GoogleSpell, PSpell, PSpellShell and Sp ellChecker classes

2) update spellcheck method to return the data in following format

```
array(
    'incorrect word 1'=>array('suggestion 1','suggestion 2', etc...),
    'incorrect word 2'=>array('suggestion 1','suggestion 2', etc...),
)
```

For example lets update spellcheck method of EnchantSpell.php file

...
...

```
if(!$correct) {
    //$returnData[] = trim($value);
    $returnData[trim($value)] = $this->getSuggestions($lang, trim($value));
}
```

...
...

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the first argument for of call_user_func_array like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array("PSpellShell","spellcheck"), $arguments);
```

Comment: I looked through the documentation that you linked and it doesn't appear as though spellcheck is a method implemented on the PSpellShell object.

Comment: Well, the same thing happens using $config['general.engine'] = 'GoogleSpell';

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google closed down this service. You shouldn't use it any more.